Limit on Export Size while exporting Oracle Database using SQL Developer 1.5.4
I am trying to export a large Oracle Database with dozens of tables, for import into MySQL. When I export my database using SQLDeveloper it produces a text file with all the Insert statements, but truncates the file after 1.29 GB (1,260,488 KB). I have done it multiple times with the same result. I couldn't find any option to resolve this in preferences. I can see in the output file that the last Insert Statement is truncated in the middle.
Any solution?

1.5.4?! Current version is 23.1; why don't you upgrade? I'm not saying that it'll solve your problem, but ... your version is really ancient.

Good point - Thanks @Littlefoot . It was running since ages. Installed 23.1 and the output files has swelled beyond 1.2 GB. Lets now see if I am able to handle the multi-GB file when gets completed.
